# How to write .knex-migrator to set up Ghost in Express app?

Tags: node.js, express, ghost

I want to incorporate Ghost to my Express app. So I tried following [this tutorial](https://rogerstringer.com/2015/09/07/ghost-express-middleware/), which I'm not sure if it is up-to-date still.

However, after following up all of them and tried to run `npm init`, I got an error instructing me to *run knex-migrator init* first.

However, I don't know what to write in the knex-migrator. Its documentation is sparse and I even don't know what to write [in the configuration file](https://github.com/TryGhost/knex-migrator).

I don't have my database to migrate into the app. I just want to start the blog from scratch.

So specifically, what do I have to write in the field of the configuration, especially at `migrationPath` and `filename`? When I tried to create a directory to match the path and run `knex-migrator init`, it said my migration path is wrong. But I don't know what the correct migration path points to...

Comment: Hmmm.. It seems that Ghost teams are now developing 1.0 alpha which is drastically different from the 0.11 LTS. And it was the alpha version that I tried to deploy. I'm now checking out the alpha.

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @MikeFisher It seems that in 1.0-alpha version, you don't need to write in knex-migrator. Just install it and then run it, all from `ghost` command line tools.